# estou com problema para calcular a soma 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...+ 1/n usando função recursiva

Tags: c, matemática, recursão

Estou tendo dificuldade com esta função. Segue meu código abaixo:

```
int fracao(int n)
{
    if(n == 1) return 2;
    else
    {
        return 1/n + fracao(n-1);
    }
}
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que esta errado?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: E esse problema é bem mais matemático que de programação.

Comment: Não seria isso o que deseja fazer https://ideone.com/wMzKr3

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Primeiramente, se irá fazer uma função que retorne resultados de várias divisões, mude o retorno dela para double em vez de int.

Na parte "if(n==1)", deve retornar 1, afinal 1/1 = 1 e não 2.

Por último, quando faz divisão de 2 inteiros, como no caso 1/n, o C vai retornar um número inteiro, então se quiser um resultado correto, mude a divisão para 1.0/n.

No final sua função deve ficar algo parecido com isso:

```
double fracao(int n) {
    
    if(n==1) return 1;
    
    return 1.0/n + fracao(n-1);
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigada! Sobre o retorno 2... havia entendido que se n = 1 teria a seguinte soma (seguindo o enunciado) 1 + 1/1, assim totalizando 2... erro meu!